# Saving chart.js chart to a folder (Not download)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, chart.js

I am using codeigniter and I am using chart.js to generate charts in my website I want to save a chart that, I generated, into an img file and put it in a folder in my website (not download it). How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, you convert the image to base64 format and base64 URL store
>   into a tag: For example, I am using a chart.js line chart

---

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<a type="button" id="link2" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
                }]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {
                bezierCurve : false,
                animation: {
                    onComplete: done
                }
            }
        });

        //This function is used to store the image in data-src in a tag
        function done(){
            var url = chart.toBase64Image();
            $("#link2").attr("data-src", url);
        }
    });    
</script>
```

---

> After click download ajax function is used to store the image in a
>   location

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click","#link2",function() {
        var image = $(this).attr('data-src');
        if (image) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "generateImage",
                cache: false,               
                data: {'image' : image},
                success: function(json){                        
                    try{        
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                        if (obj['STATUS']) {
                            alert('Image save successfully');
                        } else {
                            alert('Something went wrong');
                        }
                    }catch(e) {     
                        console.log('Exception while request..');
                    }       
                },
                error: function(){                      
                    console.log('Error while request..');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

> Php code for store image in the folder

---

```
public function generateImage()
    {
        $image = $_POST['image'];

        $folderPath = "uploads/";
        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
        $image_type_aux = explode("uploads/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        $name = uniqid() . '.png';
        $file = $folderPath . $name;
        $output = file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

        if ($output) {
            $status = array("STATUS"=>"true");
        } else {
            $status = array("STATUS"=>"false");
        }

        echo json_encode($status);
        exit();
    }
```